# Updating values in a txt file using Python

Tags: python, txt

I am generating numbers in a specific range with a specific stepsize. I am saving these numbers to a `.txt` file as shown below. But I want to update this file everytime I run the code. I present the current and expected output.

```
Start = 0
End = 11
Stepsize = 1

filename = f"All_values.txt"   

for i in range(Start, End, Stepsize):
    with open(filename, 'a') as f:
        f.writelines('\n')
        f.write(str(i))
```

The current output after running the code twice is

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

The expected output after running the code twice is

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems:

You need to use the "w" option to write the file instead of "a", which appends to the file.

And since you do not want to delete and rewrite the file after each number printed, you have to exchange the loops.

```
Start = 0
End = 11
Stepsize = 1

filename = f"All_values.txt"   

with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    for i in range(Start, End, Stepsize):
        f.writelines('\n')
        f.write(str(i))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using "a", while writing to the file, which means appending. Change it to "w". It'll give the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

As others wrote you, 'w' is the correct mode.
In addition, I would use an f-string to simplify the code further. However, f-strings exist only starting from python 3.

```
start_included, end_excluded, step = 0, 11, 1

filename = f"All_values.txt"   

with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    for i in range(start_included, end_excluded, step):
        f.write(f"{i}\n")
```

Another point - which the others catched was - that the entire for-loop should be inside the `with open() as f` expression.
Otherwise the code will open and close the file for every item (11 items) and overwrite what it wrote before.
This is the original reason, why you had to use the 'a' mode.